# how to initialize variable in javascript with HTML code directly

Tags: javascript, html, svg, snap.svg

How can I initialize a variable in JavaScript with a direct HTML code?

I am trying to put an `animate` tag in a variable so that I can append to the svg whenever a `mouseover` event occurs. I am using snap.svg.

```
var g = HTML CODE
var s = Snap("#svg");
s.mouseover(function(){
    s.append(g);
});
```

Something like that. I know this syntax is wrong. I didn't want to write this tag in my html code but keep it hidden and then append it

Comment: Don't use `[tag:xxx]` for every keyword in your post, it makes it very hard to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way:

```
var someHTML = '<div>Heeeyy</div>',
    someElem = document.getElementById('someElement'); 

someElem.onmouseover = function(){
    someElem.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', someHTML );
    someElem.onmouseover = null; // Remove this if you want it to happen on every mouseover event
}
```

Alternatively, you can create a new element with `document.createElement('DIV')` and set the `innerHTML` to the desired html. Then append the created element with `appendChild` on the parent (desired element).

Comment: actually im using SVG i can't append DIV rather i am trying to append [tag:animateTransfom] into the svg as child

Comment: Well then don't create a div, but an animate element and then append it. After you have created it, you can add attributes to it with  something like `elem.setAttribute("repeatCount", "indefinite")`

Comment: i have set the attributes, appended to the required group in svg, Its working quite well but still animateTransform is like dead(not working at all) until i open developer window.select it in console click on edit as html and do nothing and press enter it starts..

Comment: animateTransform doesn't really have all that good support for all browsers. As you tagged the question with that, I'll add a Snap alternative.

Answer (score 1):

animateTransform doesn't have good support on some browsers like IE, so I tend to stay away from using that method, if something like Snap is available. If it is, I would do something similar to the following...

```
s = Snap(400, 620);
var c = s.circle(10,10,10);
var myMarkup = '<g><rect x="20" y="20" width="100" height="100"></g>'
c.mouseover( function() {
  s.append( Snap.parse( myMarkup ) )
  s.select('g').animate({ transform: 't50,50' }, 3000)
})
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwr40k2y/2/) (hover over circle)

If you were just doing the markup to add an animateTransform element, you can skip the parsing/appending stuff as well, as thats not needed.